# Protobuf-net c# serialization/deserialization of list result in empty collection

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

i'm trying to serialize and deserialize a `List<T>`.

The final objective is serializing list of objects / object for an API.

Protobuf-net 2.3.17 (last one at the time of writing)

After some readings i haven't yet resolved this problem.
this is the simple code i use for test but is also used in my serialization/deserialization classes:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
   {
      Serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
      var x = stream.ToArray();

      using (var stream2 = new MemoryStream(x))
        {
          var r = Serializer.Deserialize<List<Host>>(stream);
        }
    }
```

data is a `List<Host>` (150~ elements)

and host is a simple class:

```
[Serializable]
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic, SkipConstructor = true)]
    public class Host
    {
        public Guid GidHost { get; set; }
        public int IdA { get; set; }
        public string HostName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(StatusEnum.Undefined)]
        public HostStatusEnum Status { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }
        ecc.. (some other public primitive variables)

       [Serializable]
       public enum StatusEnum
       {
           Undefined = 0,
           Ok = 1,
           Offline = 2
       }
}
```

while x  (i guess) is correctly serialized (x contains 33000 bytes)
r is a collection with 0 elements.

what is wrong, what i am missing?

Thank you

Comment: You're using stream when deserializing, not stream2. So the memory stream position is probably at the end... seek to the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
using (var stream2 = new MemoryStream(x))
{
  var r = Serializer.Deserialize<List<Host>>(stream);
}
```

You are deserializing from `stream`, not `stream2`. `stream` is currently positioned *at the end*, and therefore effectively has 0 bytes available to read. 0 bytes is actually perfectly valid protobuf, and in this case would represent an empty list.

Options:

- deserialize from `stream2`
- rewind `stream`
- use `Serializer.DeepClone`

In this scenario, I would suggest the final option, as it will avoid the extra array allocation. From 3.0 onwards `DeepClone` may also choose different serialization storage strategies (`Stream`, `Pipe`, etc) to best fit your platform - so: on .NET Core 2.1 it might prefer to use `Pipe` and exploit "spans" etc.

```
var r = Serializer.DeepClone(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried r with stream2?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20573579)

Comment: I'm undeleting this, because despite the review queue flagging it: it is absolutely correct and valid. Sometimes a terse answer is right. Advice for @schen993 though: try to be more explicit about what you mean. You were 100% right here, but it wasn't obvious.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for undeleting.... and was just trying to "answer the question"......Everyone (I'm not saying you) is just so focused on ditching other people's posts - what happened to "answer the question"? "This does not provide an answer to the question" - does this answer the question?

AeonDave, Please mark as answer if it solved your problem

Comment: @schen993 I think if you'd have added just a few more words explaining why this was a problem, it would have been very positively received.

Comment: Hey! I posted the answer first!